# How to transfer highlighted cells in Excel 2007 from one table to another in the same sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I would like to create a code that transfer the content of the highlighted cells from one table to another in the same sheet with the content, I use button to copy the content, but I would like to create a macro the transfer the content dynamically by clicking on a button, when the user change the content of the highlighted cells of the first table the content changes automatically in the second table or by clicking on the button again.

I use this code to highlight the cells

```
' Set of highlighted cells indexed by row number
Dim highlightedCells As New Collection

' Scan existing sheet for any cells coloured 'red' and initialise the
'  run-time collection of 'highlighted' cells.
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
    Dim existingHighlights As Range
    ' Reset the collection of highlighted cells ready to rebuild it
    Set highlightedCells = New Collection
    ' Find the first cell that has its background coloured red
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Set existingHighlights = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("", _
                                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                                    SearchFormat:=True)
    ' Process for as long as we have more matches
    Do While Not existingHighlights Is Nothing
        cRow = existingHighlights.Row
        ' Add a reference only to the first coloured cell if multiple
        ' exist in a single row (will only occur if background manually set)
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
            Call highlightedCells.Add(existingHighlights.Address, CStr(cRow))
        On Error GoTo 0
        ' Search from the cell after the last match. Note an error in Excel
        '  appears to prevent the FindNext method from finding formats correctly
        Application.FindFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Set existingHighlights = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("", _
                                                    After:=existingHighlights, _
                                                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                    MatchCase:=False, _
                                                    SearchFormat:=True)
        ' Abort the search if we've looped back to the top of the sheet
        If (existingHighlights.Row < cRow) Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
    Dim hCell As String
    Dim cellAlreadyHighlighted As Boolean
    hCell = ""

    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
      hCell = highlightedCells.Item(CStr(Target.Row))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (hCell <> "") Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(hCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        If (hCell = Target.Address) Then
            Call highlightedCells.Remove(CStr(Target.Row))
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
        Else
            Call highlightedCells.Remove(CStr(Target.Row))
            Call highlightedCells.Add(Target.Address, CStr(Target.Row))
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Else
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
          highlightedCells.Remove (CStr(Target.Row))
        On Error GoTo 0
        Call highlightedCells.Add(Target.Address, CStr(Target.Row))
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
    Cancel = True
      ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
End Sub
```

And I use this code to copy the highlighted cells:

```
Sub CopyCat()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="P@ssw0rd"
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim c As Range
j = 1
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each c In Worksheets("MB").Range("A1:O" & LR)
      If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            c.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("MB").Range("J" & j)
        j = j + 1
        End If
Next c
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="P@ssw0rd"

End Sub
```

Please Help !!!!

Comment: Since you just want to change any cells in the second table, when cells in the first table are changed, why not (in the second table) create a link to the original cells?  Like in your sheet2, have the cells you want updated linked to their value in Sheet1.  Does that make sense?  That way, changing a value in Sheet1 automatically updates Sheet2, without need for a macro/VB.

Comment: Please can you tell me how to link it ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the whole table and using the values to populate the table on the second page, why not (for those items you want to update, as the sheet1 gets updates) just leave a "link" back to the original table.  You could either set it literally to the cell it refers to, or more robustly, use something like Index/Match.  See below:

This is an example of Sheet1 (the data you want copied onto a second sheet).  I have highlighted the "Salary" column, to reflect that the user is asked to change these.

[image]

And in your sheet 2, you can use various ways of "linking" back to the first sheet:

[image]

That way, when you go in an edit the salary for Chris or John, it'll update their salary in the second sheet, without needing to run any macros.  Is this what you're looking to do, or am I overlooking/misunderstanding something?